# How to turn off the automatic swipe to go back in navigation controller? Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, swipe, viewcontroller

I need to turn off the automatic gesture swiping to go back in navigation controller. I using Swift.

I have already searched but didn't found a solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` of your navigationController:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
```

Comment: I've already tried this in my viewDidLoad() but isn't working. Should I set it in a different place?

Comment: Yes. Inside your AppDelegate-method in the didLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: Just tried inside my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and I'm getting the next error 'AppDelegate' does not have a member named 'navigationController'

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
return false;
}
```

I found this after a couple little searches. Not sure if its correct or not.

Comment: The first line isn't recognized by swift.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:
Add this delegate in your `UIViewController`: `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Then in your `viewDidLoad()` method add the next line:

```
self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

and finally add this delegate method:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Good luck!