# How to disable navigation controller slide right in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to disable the pull left feature on a navigation window that you see here.

[image]

But I not sure where to start? I want the Back button to work, but not the drag left that I doing in the snapshot cause it does work for my app.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943151/how-to-turn-off-the-automatic-swipe-to-go-back-in-navigation-controller-swift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to do:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

^^ This is the gesture recogniser that it uses for that transition.

Though I would highly discourage doing this unless you have a very good reason. It is a standard iOS behaviour and is great for accessibility (for users who can't reach the top left corner with one hand, or have a 6 plus).

Comment: For Objective-C, do this:

self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;